# How to control the size of a rectangle marker in a scatter plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to make a scatter plot, but I want the markers to be rectangles with a fixed size in `x` and a different fixed size in the `y` direction. In the manual it says that I can have a `mark=cube*`, and I could set the size along each axis with `/pgfplots/cube/size x={}` and `/pgfplots/cube/size y={}`. I have tried to put that keys both in the `axis` and `addplot` keys, but it doesn't change the size of the markers.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        /pgfplots/cube/size x=1,
        /pgfplots/cube/size y=2,
    ]
    \addplot[
        only marks,
        mark=cube*,
    ] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this for a 2D scatter plot?

Comment: Try with `mark options={xscale=1, yscale=2}`. BTW, `axis` option should be closed by `]` and not by `}`.

Comment: @Zarko That works great. Feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept it. Also, is that somewhere in the PGFPlots manual? A simple "CTRL + F" doesn't show that anywhere. I guess I would have to find the correct scale I want by trial and error; or is there a way to specify it in units of the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `cube/size ...`, works only in 3d diagrams, for example

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
\addplot3[only marks,
          mark=cube*,
          cube/size x={2pt}, cube/size y={4pt},
        ] coordinates {(0,0,0) (1,1,1) (2,2,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but not in 2d. In such cases you need to use `mark options={xscale=1, yscale=2}`, for example:

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
\addplot[only marks,
         mark=square*,
         mark options={xscale=1, yscale=2}
        ] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]